# Limits when using the SQL API

Tags: carto

i use the [SQL-API](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/sql-api.html) as described in here:

And i find the following issues undocumented:

1. How many requests per second can i send to the SQL-API, before the user gets slowed down/blocked? I would like to throttle myself and also make calculations, how long those requests will take.
2. How many statements can be put in a batch? Or is this purely a limit on the POST request? Whatever fits in the POST request, will be executed?

Does anybody know or can clarify?

Answer (score 1):

This information is available under the [Terms and condition](http://cartodb.com/terms/#excessive) page.

> You agree that use beyond two million requests (tiles or data requests), including, but not limited to, requests that result from Distributed Denial of Service (DDoS) attacks, within a thirty day period will be considered Excessive Use. You may be responsible for additional fees for Excessive Use as described above.
>
> Also, there is a max number of WRITE SQL statements per API call: 10,000 rows or 1GB of data (payload of a SQL API call); and a max number of API Calls:
>
> FREE  1 every 10 seconds
>
> STANDARD ACCOUNT  1 per second
>
> ENTERPRISE    5 per second